# How to access this variable?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I'm new to VB and I'm currently migrating a vb6 app I did not write to .net and I'm struggling with this error,

```
If TypeOf Application.OpenForms.Item(i) Is frmAddChangeDelete Then
            'UPGRADE_ISSUE: Control ctrlAddChangeDelete1 could not be resolved because it was within the generic namespace Form. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="084D22AD-ECB1-400F-B4C7-418ECEC5E36E"'

            If **Application.OpenForms.Item(i).ctrlAddChangeDelete1.ParentFormNumber = intFormNumber** Then

                If Application.OpenForms.Item(i).Text = "Add Proofed Expense Items" Then
                    boolAddProofed = True
                    Exit For
```

ctrlAddChangeDelete1 is supposedly calling the friend class ctrlAddChangeDelete from a separate VB file, so I'm not sure why it's saying that

`"'ctrlAddChangeDelete1' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'."`

Any help is appreciated, thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Application.OpenForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a collection not strongly typed.
When you reference elements there you get back a generic Form.
In a generic Form there is no control named *ctrlAddChangeDelete1*

If you have a form derived class named *frmAddChangeDelete* and this class has a control named *ctrlAddChangeDelete1* then you need to cast the reference stored in the OpenForms collection to your specific form class before trying to reference that control.

Moreover, to access that control from external code, you should also have the Modifiers property set to Public instead of the default Internal. Otherwise you will not be able to access the control from any code external to the class.

To retrieve correctly your form you can write

```
Dim delForm = Application.OpenForms.
                         OfType(Of frmAddChangeDelete)
                         FirstOrDefault()
If delForm Is Nothing Then
    ' No form of type frmAddChangeDelete is present in the collection
    ' write here your message and exit ?
Else 
    ' Now you can use delForm without searching again in the collection
    ......
```

The code above uses the [IEnumerable.OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) extension and this requires the `Imports System.Linq`.
If you don't want to use this then you can always use the [TryCast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyy863x8.aspx) operator to get the reference to the correct class

```
' Still you need a for loop up ^^^^ before these lines
Dim delForm = TryCast(Application.OpenForms(i), frmAddChangeDelete)
if delForm Is Nothing then 
   ....
else
   ....
```

Comment: I undestand the error a lot better now, thank you!
Although now I'm wondering in there's something wrong with my namespaces/references because apparently OfType doesn't exist within OpenForms...

Comment: [IEnumerable.OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) extensions requires the System.Linq namespace (You should already have the reference but still you need Imporst System.Linq)